# Using class_werights with multiple loss functions

Tags: tensorflow

My question is that I have network with two outputs and each output has its own loss function. I want to apply the `class_weight`  on only one of the output, how I can achieve that. I searched the documentation of `class_weights` and  I don't think it support multiple outputs. Because they didn't mentioned it. Also I don't know exactly the current class-wegiht strategy . Is it  going to apply for both outputs or it will be applied on only the first one.

Any one have thoughts about what should I do?

#### EDIT, adding example:

```
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self._num_classes, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', name = 'out_1')(input)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self._num_classes, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', name = 'out_2')(input)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=[x1, x2])

model.compile(loss={'out_1': loss1, 'out_2': loss2},
                  optimizer=opt, metrics={'out_1': 'categorical_accuracy', 'out_2': 'categorical_accuracy'})

class_weight_dict = {0: 0.022, 1: 0.01, 2: 0.06, 3: 0.12, 4: 0.26, 5: 0.44, 6: 0.068}  # this represent the weights for each class in my 7 classes dataset for example

model.fit(dataset_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
               class_weight=class_weight_dict,
              validation_data=dataset_val),
              callbacks=call_backs)
```

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example. I guess it'd make it easier to help

Comment: I added minimal example to clarify the issue. Thanks.